# WPF equivalent of Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, childwindow

In WPF we have `Window.ShowDialog()` which allows showing a modal dialog box.

In WinForms there is similar functionality but it *also* has an overload `Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window)` which allows an `IWin32Window owner` to be passed in.  That way the new dialog is not modal, and always maintains a z-order directly above its owner.

How would I get this same functionality using WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property on a Window.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Jonathan.Peppers's answer:

Say you had a Window you named `FooWindow`, and in `BarWindow.cs` you wanted to create and execute an instance. You can create a modal version of `FooWindow` as simple as this:

`new FooWindow(){ Owner = this }.ShowDialog();`

That would assume you didn't need a reference to you instance, obviously, but you get the idea?